# Replace all NA values with the (minimum value/2) value for each column, in large 6000+ column dataset

Tags: r, replace, min, na, calculation

Instead of just substituting NAs with the mean value, I need to substitute the NA with the minimum value in the column, divided by 2. (Our statistician asked me to perform this on our data - I am not a statistician so following their instructions)

This is glimpse of my data:

```
data

        Group sp.Q13813.SPTN1_HUMAN sp.O14773.TPP1_HUMAN sp.P11137.MTAP2_HUMAN
1 Premutation           10713983468            367492324            2134747097
2 Premutation           10789498495            343303410            2677825476
3 Premutation           11134883489            383589325            2132552280
4 Premutation            9723552595            269965000            2262740921
5 Premutation           11175156282            359864993            1419225650
6 Premutation           10959077349            258095035            3343267633
7 Premutation           10770809133            331554977            2763604046
8 Premutation           11098182537            344384433            2198718886
```

This is my code thus far, but i'm getting a function debug error message:

```
data_ <- lapply(data, function(x) replace(x, is.na(x), (min(x, na.rm = TRUE)/2)))

Message: function (x, list, values) 
{
  x[list] <- values
  x
}
```

Comment: You are getting the error because you are trying to divide 2 for a character column (first column) this should do it: lapply(data[2:4], function(x) replace(x, is.na(x), min(x, na.rm = TRUE) / 2))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should apply the function only on numeric columns. Ignoring the first column (`Group`) here since it is not numeric.

```
cols <- sapply(data, is.numeric)
data[cols] <- lapply(data[cols], function(x) 
                     replace(x, is.na(x), min(x, na.rm = TRUE)/2))
```

Or with `dplyr` we can use `mutate_if` which will automatically select numeric columns

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, ~replace(., is.na(.), min(., na.rm = TRUE)/2))
```

Comment: That solved it - I didn't realize the character-containing columns were causing a problem. Thank you @Ronak Shah